# How is this named self-invoked function being passed an argument?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

Good evening,

I have been trying to wrap my head about this, below, code written by Chris Coyer.

I understand this is a self-invoked function named 'supports', but what I don't understand is how 'supports' is passed an argument (as seen below in the // Test section). Please could someone explain this or point me in the right direction for further reading?

```
// Generic Testing Function
var supports = (function() {
   var div     = document.createElement('div'),
       vendors = 'Khtml Ms O Moz Webkit'.split(' '),
       len     = vendors.length;  

    return function(prop) {
      if ( prop in div.style ) return true;  

      prop = prop.replace(/^[a-z]/, function(val) {
         return val.toUpperCase();
      });  

      while(len--) {
         if ( vendors[len] + prop in div.style ) {
            return true;
         }
      }
      return false;
   };
})();  

// Test
if ( supports('flowInto') ) {
   $("html").addClass('cssregions');
} else {
   $("html").addClass('no-cssregions');
}
```

Comment: May someone enlighten me, but issn't it bugged? I mean, `len` never get's reset, so how will this work on repeated calls?

Comment: why would you call it repeatedly? If the browser supports it, the HTML element gets the class

Comment: @danwellman maybe to check other stuff?

Comment: Wouldn't `len` be re-evaluated everytime `supports` is called?

Comment: @Check12 no `len` get's set during the execution of the outer anonymous function. `len     = vendors.length;` this get's executed only once, regardless of the calls to the inner function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see what `supports` is:

```
var supports = (function() {
    /* ... */
})();
```

OK, so `supports` is the return value of an anonymous function that gets invoked on the spot. What does this anonymous function return?

```
    return function(prop) {
      if ( prop in div.style ) return true;  

      prop = prop.replace(/^[a-z]/, function(val) {
         return val.toUpperCase();
      });  

      while(len--) {
         if ( vendors[len] + prop in div.style ) {
            return true;
         }
      }
      return false;
   };
```

Alright, so the return value of this function (which is what `support` holds as we said above) is actually *a function* that takes one argument (`prop`).

So at this point it should become clear that it's perfectly logical to do what the test section does, i.e. call that function:

```
if ( supports('flowInto') ) /* .... */
```

It's really not complicated when you know where to start from.

Comment: Thank you for the explaination, Jon, and everyone else that helped me understand this sample. :)

Answer (score 1):

The self-invoking function is returning a function, which accepts an argument.

So, the SIF gets executed, returns

```
return function(prop) {
  if ( prop in div.style ) return true;  

  prop = prop.replace(/^[a-z]/, function(val) {
     return val.toUpperCase();
  });  

  while(len--) {
     if ( vendors[len] + prop in div.style ) {
        return true;
     }
  }
  return false;
};
```

this guy here. And this function reference is stored into the `supports` variable.

Answer (score 1):

`supports` is the function returned by the anonymous, self-invoking function (this one):

```
function(prop) {
    if (prop in div.style) return true;
    prop = prop.replace(/^[a-z]/, function(val) {
        return val.toUpperCase();
    });
    while (len--) {
        if (vendors[len] + prop in div.style) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};​
```

So the argument-passing in question passes the `prop` argument.

Answer (score 0):

That's a self-invoking function *that returns a function*.

`supports` is assigned the the function that the self-invoking function returns.

Answer (score 0):

the variable 'supports' is receiving a new function, which can be seen in the line

```
return function(prop) {
```